# How many tables we can create in mysql data base?

Tags: mysql

How many tables we can create in mysql data base? is there any limit in number of tables in MYSQL database?

Comment: May be he/she is not aware of Stackoverflow procedure. You have to approve the answer from the user once you satisfied with the answer and it works for you.

Comment: "More than you'll ever need" ... and if you need more than a few dozen (on a small-medium project), then red-flags should likely start going off.

Comment: @magicmike See link above. I find it easiest just to copy'n'paste it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[MySql has no limit on the number of databases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-count-limit.html), though your underlying filesystem may impose limitations that *practically* limit the number of tables in a MySQL database.

> MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. *InnoDB [only] permits up to 4 billion tables.*

It also has a nice [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html). And there's [google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mysql%20table%20limit).